# Internet explorer and Safari - how can i suspend for 5 years using my firewall if no WebRTC default available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, webrtc

I am trying to make a firewall/filter for those users who do not have default WebRTC will be suspended for 5 years in my domain, together as community we are growing to suspend as much as we can.

So, How do i detect

> Internet explorer mobile

and

> iOS safari

users? 
which i want to suspend in my firewall list, cause they by default do not have webRTC and always place complain.

```
  waitForWhichBrowser(function() {
    var o = document.getElementById('container');

    try {
      Browsers = new WhichBrowser({
        useFeatures:        true,
        detectCamouflage:   true
      });

      var n = Browsers.browser.name;
      var v = Browsers.browser.version.major;
      var oo = Browsers.os;
      var d = Browsers.isType('desktop'); // true
      //var a = Browsers.isType('mobile', 'tablet', 'media');   // false
      o.innerHTML = 'Using ' + Browsers + '<br/><small>Desktop PC: ' + d  +  ' ' + oo +  '</small>';            
      var g = document.getElementById('getit');     

      if (n == "Chrome") {
        if (v < 32 ) {           
          g.innerHTML = "No WebRTC. Community Suspended this browser for 5 years. Please use  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/";  
        }
      } else if (n == "Chromium") {
        if (v < 31 ) {
          g.innerHTML = "UDP BUG - No WebRTC. Community Suspended this browser for 5 years. Please use  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/";   
        }   
      } else if (n == "Opera") {        
        if (v <19 ) {
          // suspend them
        }
      } else if (n == "Internet Explorer") {
          g.innerHTML = "No WebRTC. Community Suspended this browser for 5 years. Please use  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/";        
      } else if (n == "Firefox") {
          g.innerHTML = "UDP BUG - No WebRTC available by default suspend it. Community Suspend, No WebRTC No standard web browser. Suspended this browser for 5 years. Please use https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/";               
      } else if (n == "Safari") {
          g.innerHTML = "No WebRTC. Community Suspended this browser for 5 years. Please use  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/";            
      } else {        
          g.innerHTML = "No WebRTC. Community Suspended this browser for 5 years. Please use  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/";           
      }

    } catch (e) {
      o.innerHTML = 'Oops, something went wrong:<br> <small>' + e + '</small>';
    }
  });
```

Comment: Try using [WhichBrowser](http://whichbrowser.net) for browser detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you do feature detect rather than browser detect to decide which browsers to suspend. So a simple code given below should suffice your need:

```
if(window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection) {
    //supported
} else {
    //unsupported
}
```

Comment: Does it also works for Android Tablet, Mobile, IPhone , IPad, Windows Mobile, Nokia, Blackberry etc?